# Footer is not in bottom in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I made a new component for footer. I used a template given below, but the footer is not in the bottom where it should. I have applied the footer component using a service just to make it visible or not on a certain route like login etc..

I have tried applying many solutions given but no luck, can anyone help in this?

app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-breakingnews></app-breakingnews>
<ngx-spinner bdColor="rgba(51,51,51,0.8)" size="medium" type="ball-atom" color="#d9534f" [fullScreen]="true">
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color:white;padding-top: 50px;"><strong> Fetching All the News......</strong></p>
</ngx-spinner>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

footer.component.html

```
<footer class="footer kilimanjaro_area" *ngIf="footer.visible">
    <!-- Top Footer Area Start -->
    <div class="foo_top_header_one section_padding_100_70">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="kilimanjaro_part">
                        <h5>About Us</h5>
                        <p>It includes rich features & contents. It's designed & developed based on One Page/
                            Multi-page Layout,blog themes,world press themes and blogspot. You can use any layout
                            from any demo anywhere.</p>
                        <p>webblogoverflow is completely creative, clean & 100% responsive website. Put your
                            business into next level with Webublogoverflow.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="kilimanjaro_part m-top-15">
                        <h5>Social Links</h5>
                        <ul class="kilimanjaro_social_links">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Twitter</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pinterest</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i> YouTube</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Linkedin</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="kilimanjaro_part">
                        <h5>Tags Widget</h5>
                        <ul class=" kilimanjaro_widget">
                            <li><a href="#">Classy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Creative</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Multipurpose</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Minimal</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Classic</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Medical</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="kilimanjaro_part m-top-15">
                        <h5>Important Links</h5>
                        <ul class="kilimanjaro_links">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Terms &
                                    Conditions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>About Licences</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Help & Support</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Careers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Privacy Policy</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Community &
                                    Forum</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="kilimanjaro_part">
                        <h5>Latest News</h5>
                        <div class="kilimanjaro_blog_area">
                            <div class="kilimanjaro_thumb">
                                <img class="img-fluid"
                                    src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/--C1wpaf_S4M/W7V__10nRoI/AAAAAAAAK24/1NSfapuYSIY0f0wzXY9NgoH0FjQLT07YACKgBGAs/s1600/maxresdefault.jpg"
                                    alt="">

                            </div>
                            <a href="#">Your Blog Title Goes Here</a>
                            <p class="kilimanjaro_date">21 Jan 2018</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kilimanjaro_blog_area">
                            <div class="kilimanjaro_thumb">
                                <img class="img-fluid"
                                    src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/--C1wpaf_S4M/W7V__10nRoI/AAAAAAAAK24/1NSfapuYSIY0f0wzXY9NgoH0FjQLT07YACKgBGAs/s1600/maxresdefault.jpg"
                                    alt="">
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">Your Blog Title Goes Here</a>
                            <p class="kilimanjaro_date">21 Jan 2018</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kilimanjaro_blog_area">
                            <div class="kilimanjaro_thumb">
                                <img class="img-fluid"
                                    src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/--C1wpaf_S4M/W7V__10nRoI/AAAAAAAAK24/1NSfapuYSIY0f0wzXY9NgoH0FjQLT07YACKgBGAs/s1600/maxresdefault.jpg"
                                    alt="">
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">Your Blog Title Goes Here</a>
                            <p class="kilimanjaro_date">21 Jan 2018</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="kilimanjaro_part">
                        <h5>Quick Contact</h5>
                        <div class="kilimanjaro_single_contact_info">
                            <h5>Phone:</h5>
                            <p>+255 789 54 50 40 <br> +2255 766 90 94 00</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kilimanjaro_single_contact_info">
                            <h5>Email:</h5>
                            <p>support@webblogoverflow.com <br> luckmoshy@gmail.com</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="kilimanjaro_part">
                        <h5>Latest Works</h5>
                        <div class="kilimanjaro_works">
                            <a class="kilimanjaro_works_img" href="img/gallery/1.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/1.jpg"
                                    alt=""></a>
                            <a class="kilimanjaro_works_img" href="img/gallery/4.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/4.jpg"
                                    alt=""></a>
                            <a class="kilimanjaro_works_img" href="img/gallery/5.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/5.jpg"
                                    alt=""></a>
                            <a class="kilimanjaro_works_img" href="img/gallery/7.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/7.jpg"
                                    alt=""></a>
                            <a class="kilimanjaro_works_img" href="img/gallery/10.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/10.jpg"
                                    alt=""></a>
                            <a class="kilimanjaro_works_img" href="img/gallery/11.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/11.jpg"
                                    alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer Bottom Area Start -->
    <div class=" kilimanjaro_bottom_header_one section_padding_50 text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <p>© All Rights Reserved by <a href="#">Webublogoverflow.blogspot -(with all love)<i
                                class="fa fa-love"></i></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

footer.component.css

```
/* /*********footer*******************/

.kilimanjaro_area {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.foo_top_header_one {
    background-color: #15151e;
    color: #fff;
}

.section_padding_100_70 {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.foo_top_header_one {
    color: #fff;
}

.kilimanjaro_part {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.foo_top_header_one .kilimanjaro_part>h5 {
    color: #fff;
}

.kilimanjaro_part h4, .kilimanjaro_part h5 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.kilimanjaro_single_contact_info>p, .kilimanjaro_single_contact_info>h5, .kilimanjaro_blog_area>a, .foo_top_header_one .kilimanjaro_part>p {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

p, ul li, ol li {
    font-weight: 300;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.kilimanjaro_bottom_header_one {
    background-color: #111;
}

.section_padding_50 {
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.kilimanjaro_bottom_header_one p {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}

p, ul li, ol li {
    font-weight: 300;
}

.kilimanjaro_bottom_header_one a {
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
}

a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.m-top-15 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.kilimanjaro_widget>li {
    display: inline-block;
}

p, ul li, ol li {
    font-weight: 300;
}

ol li, ul li {
    list-style: outside none none;
}

.kilimanjaro_widget a {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #888;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.kilimanjaro_links a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.kilimanjaro_links a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    font-size: 13px;
}

.top-15 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.foo_top_header_one .kilimanjaro_part>h5 {
    color: #fff;
}

.kilimanjaro_part h4, .kilimanjaro_part h5 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.kilimanjaro_social_links>li {
    display: inline-block;
}

p, ul li, ol li {
    font-weight: 300;
}

.kilimanjaro_social_links a {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #888;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
}

.kilimanjaro_blog_area .kilimanjaro_date {
    color: #27ae60;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.kilimanjaro_blog_area>p {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.kilimanjaro_works>a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 33.33333333%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.kilimanjaro_thumb {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 75px;
}

.kilimanjaro_links a i {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/* :: 18.0 Footer Area CSS */

.footer_area {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.footer_bottom p>i, .footer_bottom p>a:hover {
    color: #27ae60;
}

.social_links_area {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.social_links_area>a:hover {
    color: #27ae60;
}

.inline-style .social_links_area>a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #27ae60;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
}

.single_feature:hover .feature_text h4 {
    color: #27ae60;
}

.kilimanjaro_blog_area {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 0 0 15px 90px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.kilimanjaro_links a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make minor structural modification, add footer inside placeholder div.

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar> // set css position fixed
//place holder here and put padding at top and at the bottom
<div class="placeholder">
    <div class="inner-placeholder">
        <app-breakingnews></app-breakingnews>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
<ngx-spinner bdColor="rgba(51,51,51,0.8)" size="medium" type="ball-atom" color="#d9534f" [fullScreen]="true">
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color:white;padding-top: 50px;"><strong> Fetching All the News......</strong></p>
</ngx-spinner>
```

css:

```
.placeholder{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: calc( 100vh - 60px); //viewport height - app-navbar height
}
.inner-placeholder{
  flex: 1;// if you want center container large space else will take size of the content or apply flex-basis
}
app-footer{
 flex: auto; // up to you
}
app-navbar{
  position:fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: The data which gets loaded is dynamic and footer and data just gets merged together

Comment: Thanksss man it worked like magic thank you soo much!!!! Just one issue, when I View it on any mobile device its not taking up the whole width, we can move the screen side ways also

Comment: Is it the whole app-root, or any part of the section, like placeholder? I am not clear which part in the view not taking complete width?

Comment: The placeholder, like sometimes it gets properly in the middle, but majorly there are some space on the right side

Comment: add css width property 100vw to .inner-placeholder, let see

Answer (score 1):

To fix any element in a particular position, use the css property `position: fixed` and provide the `top|bottom` value.

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

.app {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  height: calc(100% - 120px);
  /* height of nav and footer is excluded from 100% */
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 65px 0 60px 0;
}

main p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <nav></nav>
  <main>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
  </app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the footer to stay down with short content while the footer is pushed down from the content with long content.
You can do it with these css rules:

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 100px;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to always be in the bottom and not to scroll it with the rest of the content, you can change its position `property: fixed` and you can set the `top: 90vh` or something (I don't know by heart).
That way it will be on the bottom of the page all the time.

Comment: The data which gets loaded is dynamic and footer and data just gets merged together

Answer (score 0):

use the position and bottom styling

```
.footer .kilimanjaro_area{

position:fixed;
bottom: 0px;
z-index: 2000;
}
```

Comment: The data which gets loaded is dynamic and footer and data just gets merged together

Comment: @PratikGhagare change the z-index to 2000

Comment: No not working the some part of the the footer is in the bottom but the remaining part just merges with the dymanic data